# What is that new Rubber Flooring type?

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

Somebody told me about a different laminate that is actually made from a type of rubber/plastic.

what is the product called and what are the pros/cons over conventional laminate flooring.

Comment: We'll need more information. They make rubber floors. Have for quite a while. Not sure about plastic floors, though.

Comment: I am in South Africa, and have not seen the rubber laminate floors, someone from England made reference to them. apparently the board is printed with a cover that looks like the wooden laminate, however they are made from rubber/plastic and not the chipboard. (ie exactly like laminate just made of rubber/plastic)

Comment: ah, interesting. Yea, that's new to me.

Comment: Could it be [Vinyl flooring with a wood pattern](http://www.worldfloorexpo.com/compare.php?n=PTID&v=Wood&m=4&f=10)?

Comment: yes, Perfect, sorry, i guess it was a bad question... but thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yes they have this item it is rubber backed I have some in my entryway.
you just lay it down in any pattern you want and then put an edge on it to keep it in place. I just used it for my entry and then trimmed it with wood to keep it all butted tightly together when I want to change it you can just lift it right up, no glue and easily rearranged, seems very durable I love it. Mine is wood grain style but I believe you can get it in tile or slate or rock look. I could perhaps attach a picture tomorrow if someone wants to take a look.
I found a bocks of it at a recycle store so no name of the co

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [Vinyl flooring with a wood pattern](http://www.worldfloorexpo.com/compare.php?n=PTID&v=Wood&m=4&f=10), which means the pros/cons list would look something like this...

## Vinyl

### Pros

- Affordable.
- Easy to clean.
- Easy to install.
- Fairly durable.
- Many patterns available.
- Moisture resistant.
- Quieter.
- Softer under foot.

### Cons

- Damaged by heavy/sharp objects.
- Not great for resale value.
- Prone to fading.

## Laminate

### Pros

- Affordable.
- Durable.
- Easy to clean.
- Easy to install.
- Good resale value.
- Scratch-resistant.

### Cons

- Damaged by heavy/sharp objects.
- Harder under foot.
- Noisier.
- Not a great choice for damp areas.